# How to make LinkedIn require a message for connection requests?

Tags: linkedin

I'd like to make LinkedIn require a message from people sending me a connection request. Where can I find this setting?

I've tried looking through the settings screen but couldn't find it. Searching on the internet doesn't seem to work, as it brings up advice for people who want to *send* connection requests, whereas I have the opposite end of that problem and I want to encourage would-be connections to write a brief message about who they are and what they want. This is a much less common problem, it seems. Is requiring a message to connect a LinkedIn premium feature?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to a [LinkedIn Moderator](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10197553):

> Unfortunately, there's not a setting that requires the sender to
>   include a message or to first send a message.
>
> However, there are a few different settings under the 'Invitations to
>   Connect' section regarding who can send you Invitations:
>   https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/invite-receive
>
> - Everyone on LinkedIn
> - Only people who know your email address or appear in your “Imported Contacts” list
> - Only people who appear in your “Imported Contacts” list
>
> If you select one of the last two options, the sender will not have
>   the option to Invite you unless they meet the qualification. In that
>   case, they will have an option to only send you an InMail.